# Are StackExchange and the WP Forums related, or are they completely independent entities?

Tags: discussion

Are core developers hanging out here, or are they still focused on the official WP forums? Are WP community leaders involved in this SE site? Is there a plan to rationalize the two venues?

A lot of questions, I know, but I'm really just looking for guidance as to where I should be focused going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi **@Greg**:

It's my understanding that [Matt](http://ma.tt) has taken the position that everything that is *"official"* WordPress and on WordPress.org needs to be controlled by [Automattic](http://automattic.com/) and thus WordPress Answers here on StackExchange will never be integrated with *"official"* support channels. Of course that's what an outsider has seen looking in and I could be woefully misinterpreting; if so I hope Matt or someone who can speak for him will clarify.

That said, I don't think it really matters one iota if WordPress Answers is *"official"* or not. The StackExchange platform rocks and IMO is producing far better results than the official channels for either WordPress or any other platform for which StackExchange has a site for.  So I'm actually quite happy to see it stay *"unofficial"* for at least two (2) reasons:

1. People can say and do things on WordPress Answers that might get filtered if this were an *"official"* channel,
2. The calibre of questions and of answers here is much higher than at [wordpress.org/support](http://wordpress.org/support/) in large part because developers are here and end-user bloggers congregate at WordPress' support; integration might lower the overall quality of this site.

That said, what's your interest/motivation in seeing them merged?

-Mike

Comment: yes, wp.org wants to fully own their stack. I understand and respect that decision -- and I think it's OK because we both have the same shared goal, anyway: we love WordPress!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - +1

Comment: Mike, thanks for a more comprehensive answer than my question deserved. I'm a big fan of both WP and SO. I recently found myself posting the same question in both places, remembered seeing Matt promoting this SE site on Twitter and thought I'd ask here whether there are any plans in place to merge. I'm quite happy to continue using them as independent entities. Your calibre point is interesting. I've never got into participating on the IRC channel and I have mixed success in the forum with deeper topics. It will be awesome if WPSE fills that gap.

Comment: @Greg - Cool. I've become a huge fan of this site, and not because I participate so much but instead I participate so much because I'm a huge fan. While it's not perfect *(what ever is?)* it really is an incredibly great resource. Looking forward to your ongoing participation her as well!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I can see this site overtaking WP.org because of the SEO that StackExchange has on the internet nowadays honestly. I think sometime in the future WP.org would embrace this as an official level of support. Time will tell though ;)

Comment: @Zack - You **nailed** it with the SEO comment! That is what originally made me aware of StackOverflow. After a while I realized that the best answer to a PHP/MySQL/jQuery question was almost always on the StackOverflow page *(as opposed to pages that ranked higher in the Google search results)* which is when I became a believer in the StackExchange mechanism in general.

Answer (score 4):

> Are core developers hanging out here

Some are, by their personal choice to.

> Are WP community leaders involved in this SE site?

Define *community leaders*? There are a lot of sub-communities in larger WP picture and this site is one of those.

> Is there a plan to rationalize the two venues?

Not sure what you mean by *rationalize*. Overall they are likely to remain separate and each on its own course.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. By rationalize, I meant move towards a single venue over time. By "Overall they are likely to remain separate and each on its own course" it sounds like thats a no from your perspective.

Comment: @Greg yes, in my opinion any kind of merge is highly unlikely.